# Is there any proxy software (like proxifier) which can use Kerberos authentication?

Tags: kerberos

My company uses PAC file to restrict any outgoing traffic through proxy server. The problem is, a lot of software does not provide the option to 'use IE setting', so that they cannot be connected to the internet.

I checked this PAC file up and found the right proxy server. But after I tried to use the proxy setting for these IE-unfriendly software, they still cannot get online. I used chrome to capture some packages and found the http header containing some Negotiation data. So I assume this proxy server uses some auto login mechanism like NTLM or kerberos.

But after I downloaded the famous Proxifier and tried to reroute the net traffic for some software, NTLM method did not work. I get the 502 error. Bummer...

Any hero comes to help! Am I thinking in the wrong way? Merci beacoup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programming question but, did you try

- cntlm (http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) or
- ntlmaps (http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)?

Hope this helps

Comment: This for your input. I will try them right now. Can one tell which authentication method is used from the HTTP header? Here is the proxy part: Proxy-Authorization:Negotiate xxxxx. I am wondering my company is not using the NTLM but keroberos. And I did some background check that Keroberos is more sophisticated maybe? NTLM is just for the backward compatibility? Thanks again.

Comment: I tried ntlmaps. It works! Thanks man. But still, I am quite curious about the NTLM and kerberos thing. Waiting for your ideas~

Comment: Great! If that worked for you, can you please put the answer as accepted answer?